# Why typescript don't aggregate one module in different files to single js function?

Tags: typescript

I have one module in two files:

file1.ts:

```
module foo {
export function bar1() {
    alert("1");
}
}
```

file2.ts:

```
module foo {
export function bar2() {
    alert("2");
}
```

}

and output file is:

```
 // out.js
 var foo;
(function (foo) {
function bar1() {
    alert("1");
}
foo.bar1 = bar1;
})(foo || (foo = {}));

var foo;
(function (foo) {
function bar2() {
    alert("2");
}
foo.bar2 = bar2;
})(foo || (foo = {}));
```

instead of aggregating this two modules into single js function?

Comment: This would probably be better asked on [CodePlex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/), as it is a decision by the designers of the language/compilers. Each file is compiled today independently....

Answer (score 1):

That is the way the language works. It is similar to the following code:

```
var foo = 123;
foo = 456;
```

It should be safe to rewrite this code as:

```
var foo = 456;
```

But the typescript compiler will not do this for you. Similarly the compiler is generating what you are asking it to do. You ask for a `module` and it generates one for you.

**Update:** If you don't want this redundancy you can write the code in multiple ways one of which is as simple as :

```
var foo:{
    a?:number;
    b?:string;
} = {}


// file a 
foo.a = 123;

// file b
foo.b = '123';
```

Comment: ok, but is there way to share not exported vars across multiple files when I have same module? if it would be the same module in output then it won't be problem to have this feature